# Browser supported SSL/TLS protocols

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, browser

I want to get the 'Browser supported SSL/TLS protocols' in my ASP.NET VB page.

How will i get this.

From the HTML page properties I can view:

[image: HTML page Connection property]

I want to get the highlighted portion in code.

Can I get that using an HttpWebRequest / BrowserCapabilities object??

Comment: No screenshot attached ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant : I have edited with screenshot